# Dynamic build lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda

So, I started to build a small test application to test lambda expressions. I found several examples here and elsewhere but I just don't get them.

Can anybody explain my how to build an expression by using textboxes or any other variables?

My Test List

```
List<People> lPeople = new List<People> 
{
    new People { Name= "Jean", LastName = "Borrow", Age= 21 } ,
    new People { Name= "Dean", LastName = "Torrow", Age= 20 }
};
```

Working lambda Expression

```
IEnumerable<People> result = lPeople.Where(p => p.Age < 21);
dgv_1.DataSource = result.ToList();
dgv_1.Update();
```

How can I build the expressions dynamically?

Something like `lPeople.Where(p => p.LastName == Textbox.Text);` (which of course doesn't work)

Thanks!

Edit: Added some code to the solution below

```
Int32 iAge;
Boolean bSuc = Int32.TryParse(tb_filter_age.Text, out iAge);
if (!bSuc)
{
    iAge = 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you could have mis-typed the name of the textbox control. Is it TextBox1? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"which of course doesn't work"

What happens when you try it? By the look of it, that's the kind of thing I do all the time.

To switch operations based on a ComboBox specifying the operator:

```
int age = int.Parse(textBoxAge.Text);

IEnumerable<People> result;
if (comboBoxOperator.Text == "=")
    result = lPeople.Where(p => p.Age == age);
else if (comboBoxOperator.Text == "<")
    result = lPeople.Where(p => p.Age < age);
else
    result = lPeople.Where(p => p.Age > age);

dgv_1.DataSource = result.ToList();
dgv_1.Update();
```

The code that converts the age string into an `int` will throw if the user enters something that can't be converted. Look up `TryParse` to avoid exceptions.

Comment: Omg, I'm so sorry! it does work :) but what about the operants?

Comment: Okay... do you mean that you want to choose the operator (==, <, >, !=, etc.) based on the state of dialog controls? (This would all go much quicker if you explained really carefully what you're trying to achieve!)

Comment: Hi Earwicker, yes, I would like that. I having an UI where the user can choose to filter a list of people by LastName and i.e. by the Age. I have a ListBox where they can select >, = and < and a Textbox where they can input an age.

Comment: To help others users:  
           
Int32 iAge; 
Boolean bSuc = Int32.TryParse(tb_filter_age.Text, out iAge);
if (!bSuc)
{
   iAge = 0;
}

Answer (score 5):

Try the Predicate Builder at http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

I used it to make an advanced search where the user could keep adding optional search criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Linq Dynamic Query Library to accomplish this.  See the following blog post from Scott Guthrie for more information:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your example lambda expression will work. How dynamic do you need it to be? If you have a static UI of 'filters' to apply to a collection, you can create code similar to the following:

```
IEnumerable<People> result = lPeople;
if (txtLastName.Text.Trim().Length != 0) 
    result = result.Where(p => p.LastName == txtLastName.Text); 
if (chkSeniors.Checked) 
    result = result.Where(p => p.Age >= 65);
dgv_1.DataSource = result.ToList();
dgv_1.Update();
```

If you want the consumer of your data source to apply truly dynamic expressions (afford them the ability to choose other fields to filter and the expressions to use), that's a more complicated feature to implement using a predicate builder tool or LINQ Expression objects.

Comment: Actually I want to modify the operators, too.

Answer (score 2):

There should be nothing wrong with the way you're going about it.  I have created a simple Windows Forms Application with a `TextBox`, a `Button`, and a `DataGridView` (with names `textBox1`, `button1`, and `dgv_1` respectively.)

Here is the code I used for the `Form1.cs` file that worked as expected:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<People> lPeople = new List<People> 
        {
            new People { Name= "Jean", LastName = "Borrow", Age= 21 } ,
            new People { Name= "Dean", LastName = "Torrow", Age= 20 }
        };

        IEnumerable<People> result = lPeople.Where(p => p.Name == textBox1.Text);

        dgv_1.DataSource = result.ToList();
        dgv_1.Update();
    }
}    

public class People
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi John, exactly the thing I did :)

Answer (score 1):

In case of dynamic user choice, I think that a more elegant solution rather then using if blocks would be to declare a variable

```
Func<People, bool> expFilter;
```

set its value based upon the user choice

```
switch(comboBoxOperator.Text)
{
   case "=":
   expFilter = p => p.Age == age;
   break;

   case ">":
   expFilter = p => p.Age > age;
   break;

   case "<":
   expFilter = p => p.Age < age;
   break;
}
```

and then pass it to the Where clause:

```
result = lPeople.Where(expFilter);
```